# Changing column of enum through DB::statement

Tags: php, laravel

I have a column of type `enum` I want to change it to type `varchar` but it brings an error that the sql syntax is not correct, please what's the solution

This is the table creation migration code

```
 class CreateCurrenciesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
   * Run the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
 public function up()
 {
    $symbols = ['₦', '$', '£'];
    Schema::create('currencies', function (Blueprint $table) use($symbols) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 50);
        $table->string('code', 5);
        $table->enum('symbol', $symbols);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{   
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
    Schema::dropIfExists('currencies');
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
}
```

This is the migration code I want to use to change the column type but keep on getting an error

```
class AddSymbolToImagesTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
       DB::statement('ALTER TABLE images ALTER COLUMN symbol VARCHAR(200)');
       // $table->text('symbol')->change();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
       // $symbols = ['₦', '$', '£'];
       // $table->enum('symbol', $symbols)->change();
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE images ALTER COLUMN symbol enum ');
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I think it's `MODIFY COLUMN`, if it's mysql/oracle. `ALTER COLUMN` is for SQLServer/MSAccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not really have anything to do with Laravel and you should also include the error next time.

To change the column type you can use `MODIFY` or `MODIFY COLUMN`.

So this would work:
`ALTER TABLE images MODIFY symbol varchar(200)`

There is a few to change the column name as you can see in the docs here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-redefine-column